# How do I decorate a react component and all its children?

Tags: javascript, decorator, reactjs, ecmascript-next

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/81913/

I am decorating a component tree and adding some meta data to my components. Works wonderfully at the top level component (A); but if I try and decorate my sub components (commented out but un-commenting illustrates the issue) - the render chain breaks and props that get passed down do not render properly (or at all). Does anyone have any insight - I have attached a fiddle above.

```
   var dec = (t, k, d) => {
  console.log('hello decoration')
  var el = React.cloneElement(d.value(), {'label': 'my-component-label'})
  return {value: () => el}
}

class B extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  //@dec
  render() {
    return <div>
        {this.props.data}
    </div>
  }
}
class A extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  @dec 
  render() {
    return <div>
        <B data={99 + 101}/>
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <A/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand recursion, you must first understand recursion!

That aside, I've used this snippet successfully in the past :

```
recursiveCloneChildren(children) {
   return React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
     let childProps = {};

     if (!child || !child.props) {
       return child;
     }
     childProps.DECORATED = true;
     childProps.children = this.recursiveCloneChildren(child.props.children);
     return React.cloneElement(child, childProps);
   });   
}
```

Just give it the `this.props.children` of a Component and it'll do the rest. in this snippet we simply add a `DECORATED` boolean value to all children.

Comment: I am giving you +1 because I believe this would work and appreciate the time you took to answer this question. That being said; I am looking for an answer that uses es7 decorators instead of a custom notion of decorating. Cheers!

Comment: You might want to update your question then, you are not decorating a component tree, you are decorating the render function, I still think this can be done the same way, But I don't enough enough experience in ES7 to actually suggest an answer